# If I cant eliminate circular references, then they should be in one class?

Tags: php, circular-dependency

a SQL implementation:

```
abstract class SQL
{
    abstract public function connect();
    abstract public function query($sql);
    abstract public function queryAndReturn($sql);
    abstract public function startTransaction();
    abstract public function commit();
    abstract public function rollback();
}

class MySQL extends SQL
{
    public function connect()
    {
        mysql_connect (....)
    }

    public function query($sql)
    {
        return mysql_query($sql);
    }

    public function queryAndReturn()
    {
        $result = $this->query($sql);
        $results = [];
        whilte ($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $results[] = $item;
        }
        return $results;
    }

    public function startTransaction()
    {
        return $this->query('START TRANSACTION');
    }

    public function commit()
    {
        return $this->query('COMMIT');
    }

    public function rollback()
    {
        return $this->query('ROLLBACK');
    }

    public function runAtomicFunction (\Closure $function)
    {
        try
        {
            $this->query('SET autocommit=0');
            $this->startTransaction();
            $function();
            $this->commit();
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            $this->rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

the last 4 methods is something like "transaction" so lets move them to another class:

```
class MySQL extends SQL
{
    public function connect()
    {
        mysql_connect (....)
    }

    public function query($sql)
    {
        return mysql_query($sql);
    }

    public function queryAndReturn()
    {
        $result = $this->query($sql);
        $results = [];
        whilte ($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $results[] = $item;
        }
        return $results;
    }


    public function getNewTransaction()
    {
        return new Transaction($this);
    }
}


class Transaction
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct(Sql $db)
    {
         $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function startTransaction()
    {
        return $this->db->query('START TRANSACTION');
    }

    public function commit()
    {
        return $this->db->query('COMMIT');
    }

    public function rollback()
    {
        return $this->db->query('ROLLBACK');
    }

    public function runAtomicFunction (\Closure $function)
    {
        try
        {
            $this->db->query('SET autocommit=0');
            $this->db->startTransaction();
            $function();
            $this->db->commit();
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            $this->db->rollback();
        }
    }
}

$sql = new MySQL();
$t = $sql->getNewTransaction();
$t->runAtomicFunction(...);
```

this is all good, but this is when circular references enter. `Sql` depends on `Transaction` and vice versa. Is this a sign that I must not separate the transaction?

Comment: This is all rather pointless. the `mysql_*()` functions are DEPRECATED and have been removed from PHP 7. You're flogging a dead dinosaur. If this is a brand new project, start using PDO instead.

Comment: yea thats right, I know that. This time ignore that fact, focus on the problem itself

Answer (score 1):

> If I cant eliminate circular references, then they should be in one class?

What benefit would it be to split them up?

I'd leave them in a single class unless you can come up with a really good reason to split them.